# CircleCI is triggering slack notification before my Cypress tests run

Tags: testing, cypress, slack, circleci

I'm totally new to testing, CircleCI, and software engineering generally. I put in a big shift today to try and write a simple Cypress test, use CircleCI to run it every hour, and post to Slack whether it was successful.

The first two I've managed, but integration with Slack has proven more difficult than I imagined. I suspect it's because I'm getting the config.yml wrong. Here's the code.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.5.1
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.28.0
  slack: circleci/slack@4.4.2

          
jobs:
  notify:
    executor:
      name: node/default
    steps:
      - slack/notify:
          channel: general
          event: fail
          template: basic_fail_1
          mentions: '@Jac'
      - slack/notify:
          channel: general
          event: pass
          template: success_tagged_deploy_1
          mentions: '@Jac'


workflows:
  version: 2
  commit-workflow:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          record: true
          store_artifacts: true

      - notify:
          context: slack-secrets
  thirty-min-workflow:
    triggers:
      - schedule:
          cron: "0,30 * * * *"
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - main
    jobs:
      - cypress/run
      - notify:
          context: slack-secrets
```

The tests are running fine, as scheduled, and a notification is pushing to Slack, but the notification triggers as soon as the build starts and is not dependent on the outcome of the tests.

I've racked my brain on this final point for hours, so I'm hoping it's an easy fix!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out. Fairly simple in the end. I added a post-steps property beneath cypress/run, which will run after the tests. By placing slack/notify beneath post-steps, it successfully ran after my tests and reflected the result.

Here's the config.yml file.

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.5.1
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.28.0
  slack: circleci/slack@4.4.2

workflows:
  version: 2
  commit-workflow:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          post-steps:
            - slack/notify:
                channel: general
                event: fail
                template: basic_fail_1
                mentions: '@Jack'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a when attribute to the cypress job and check for on_success value, if the job is successful then trigger slack notify job - for more help - https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#the-when-attribute